# CentOS TCP server does not respond to SYN packet

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, redis

We are running Redis server on CentOS and connect to it from CentOS clients.
Most of requests are successfully done but the server does not respond to SYN packet from clients sometimes.

At that time, client TCP socket state was SYN_SENT and after retries client gave up connection.

tcpdump results:

```
18:11:05.031716 IP 192.168.1.110.56287 > 192.168.1.100.6379: Flags [S], seq 1819611675, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 774050308 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:11:05.892703 IP 192.168.1.110.42376 > 192.168.1.100.6379: Flags [S], seq 1513100388, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 773648381 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:11:05.892723 IP 192.168.1.100.6379 > 192.168.1.110.42376: Flags [S.], seq 174277326, ack 1513100389, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 773688703 ecr 773648381,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:11:05.894383 IP 192.168.1.110.42376 > 192.168.1.100.6379: Flags [F.], seq 15, ack 2413, win 160, options [nop,nop,TS val 773648383 ecr 773688704], length 0
18:11:05.894533 IP 192.168.1.100.6379 > 192.168.1.110.42376: Flags [F.], seq 2413, ack 16, win 114, options [nop,nop,TS val 773688704 ecr 773648383], length 0
18:11:06.031146 IP 192.168.1.110.56287 > 192.168.1.100.6379: Flags [S], seq 1819611675, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 774051308 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:11:07.886769 IP 192.168.1.110.56288 > 192.168.1.100.6379: Flags [S], seq 686592816, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 774053163 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:11:07.886788 IP 192.168.1.100.6379 > 192.168.1.110.56288: Flags [S.], seq 1370830450, ack 686592817, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 773690697 ecr 774053163,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:11:07.887957 IP 192.168.1.110.56289 > 192.168.1.100.6379: Flags [S], seq 1024235732, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 774053164 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:11:07.887968 IP 192.168.1.100.6379 > 192.168.1.110.56289: Flags [S.], seq 2275146780, ack 1024235733, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 773690698 ecr 774053164,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:11:08.031127 IP 192.168.1.110.56287 > 192.168.1.100.6379: Flags [S], seq 1819611675, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 774053308 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:11:08.071202 IP 192.168.1.110.56288 > 192.168.1.100.6379: Flags [F.], seq 75, ack 37, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 774053347 ecr 773690697], length 0
18:11:08.071382 IP 192.168.1.100.6379 > 192.168.1.110.56288: Flags [F.], seq 37, ack 76, win 114, options [nop,nop,TS val 773690881 ecr 774053347], length 0
18:11:08.908821 IP 192.168.1.110.42378 > 192.168.1.100.6379: Flags [S], seq 4151704632, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 773651397 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:11:08.908837 IP 192.168.1.100.6379 > 192.168.1.110.42378: Flags [S.], seq 763390897, ack 4151704633, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 773691719 ecr 773651397,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

I checked some server parameters as follows:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
```

client side:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamp = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
```

Before/after of this problem, I checked /proc/net/netstat, then some values were increased(TW, DelayedACKs, TCPPrequeued, TCPHPHits, TCPPureAcks, TCPHPAcks).

Also I checked backlog overflow, but does not seem to be that.

```
# nstat -az TcpExtListenDrops
TcpExtListenDrops               0                  0.0
```

What can be considered as reason? and how can I confirm that?

Comment: When client is in `SYN_SENT` state, what do you see on the server side? I think you won't see anything. The SYN isn't reaching server.

Comment: This tcpdump log was captured on server side(192.168.1.100). SYN packets from 192.168.1.110.56287 were captured 3 times, but SYN/ACK for it was not sent.

Comment: I added logging rules to iptables(filter table, INPUT phase), then SYN packets looked went through successfully. And checked strace of redis process, but it did not call "accept" system calls for the SYN packets.